# toLowerCase with special/unicode characters throws exception

Tags: java, string, unicode

correct me if I'm wrong.

If `str` has a character such as "`•`" in it then running:

```
str.toLowerCase(Locale.English);
```

throws a null pointer exception. That's the behavior I'm seeing.

So what's the deal here? What's going on? It isn't specified that toLowerCase throws a null pointer exception.

Is there an easy way to get around this? I need the str to be lower case to be able to use a case insensitive contains check with another string, but I need the string to contain those characters for it to be displayed correctly.

What would you say is the most efficient solution if there is no "easy way?"

Comment: are you sure `str` isn't `null`?

Comment: Are you sure that `str` isn't `null`?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that str in that code snippet is null. If not, can you post the exact value of str when you get the error?

Comment: well that's just creepy.

Comment: @Sean Hahaha, I laughed when I saw that.

Comment: wow i feel dumb.
I'm iterating over a couple of strings and i knew that some of them had the character in it but turns out that one was null... not empty, i was focusing on the character :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than converting to lower case, I would suggest trying the [`String` object's `equalsIgnoreCase()` method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).

Although, as the comments do say, there is no reason for the `toLowerCase()` function to be throwing a null pointer exception unless a parameter is null. I would either use a debugger to check the state of `str` or wrap the `toLowerCase()` function call in an `if` statement and if `str` is null, do something (like throw an exception, print a statement, log a message) and not execute the function call.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, it works for me:

```
String upper = new String("asdCSD4rSDFSDFS•••••••••XCj");
String lower = upper.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println("Lower " + lower);

Lower asdcsd4rsdfsdfs•••••••••xcj
```