# Error while trying to use gwt-cal and gwt-dnd

Tags: gwt

I have a simple GWT project and I was trying to use the [gwt-cal](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-cal/) widget but I am getting errors when I try to load a page where I use the widget.

I followed the instruction [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-cal/wiki/GettingStarted) to use the gwt-cal widget, but it is not working. I have the version 0.9.3 of gwt-cal, the version 3.1.2 of gwt-dnd and I am using GWT 2.4.

Here is the page where I use the gwt-cal widget:

```
public class ClientCalendarPage extends Composite {

private VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
private Calendar calendar;

public ClientCalendarPage() {
    CalendarSettings settings = new CalendarSettings();
    settings.setEnableDragDropCreation(false);
    settings.setEnableDragDrop(false);

    calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.setSettings(settings);
    calendar.setDate(new Date()); // calendar date, not required
    calendar.setDays(3); // number of days displayed at a time, not required
    calendar.setWidth("500px");
    calendar.setHeight("400px");

    Appointment appt = new Appointment();
    appt.setStart(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 86400000));
    appt.setEnd(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 90000000));
    appt.setTitle("Test");
    appt.setStyle(AppointmentStyle.BLUE);
    calendar.addAppointment(appt);

    mainPanel.add(calendar);

    initWidget(mainPanel);
}
 }
```

Here is my app.gwt.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='minoscrossfit'>
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>                                   
 <inherits name='com.bradrydzewski.gwt.calendar.Calendar' />
 <inherits name='com.bradrydzewski.gwt.calendar.theme.google.Google' />
 <inherits name='com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.gwt-dnd'/>
 <entry-point class='com.afrsoftware.minoscrossfit.client.MinosCrossfit'/>
 <source path='client'/>
 <source path='shared'/>
</module>
```

And finaly, here is the stacktrace I get :

```
20:38:43.735 [ERROR] [minoscrossfit] Error while executing the JavaScript provider for property 'locale'

com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Property 'locale' of object  is not a function
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpacePropertyOracle.computePropertyValue(ModuleSpacePropertyOracle.java:193)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpacePropertyOracle.getSelectionProperty(ModuleSpacePropertyOracle.java:130)
at com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGeneratorUtil.getLocale(ResourceGeneratorUtil.java:543)
at com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGeneratorUtil.findResources(ResourceGeneratorUtil.java:435)
at com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGeneratorUtil.findResources(ResourceGeneratorUtil.java:290)
at com.google.gwt.resources.ext.ResourceGeneratorUtil.findResources(ResourceGeneratorUtil.java:254)
at com.google.gwt.resources.rg.CssResourceGenerator.getResources(CssResourceGenerator.java:564)
at com.google.gwt.resources.rg.CssResourceGenerator.prepare(CssResourceGenerator.java:506)
at com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.AbstractClientBundleGenerator.initAndPrepare(AbstractClientBundleGenerator.java:1043)
at com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.AbstractClientBundleGenerator.initAndPrepare(AbstractClientBundleGenerator.java:1069)
at com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.AbstractClientBundleGenerator.generateIncrementally(AbstractClientBundleGenerator.java:412)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:647)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:268)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.rebind(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:141)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:585)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
at com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.client.util.DragClientBundle.&lt;clinit&gt;(DragClientBundle.java:72)
at com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.client.util.DragEntryPoint.onModuleLoad(DragEntryPoint.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Web browser are you using for dev mode ? Are you sure you have the correct version of the GWT browser plugin ?

Comment: I am using Chrome for browser and the plugin is up to date. I tried my app on firefox this morning and it worked. After that, I tried checking out my project on another computer to make sure it was working, but it is not (on any browser with the plugin up to date)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. I was missing some locales in my project. I changed my app.gwt.xml and it worked. I used the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale#LocaleModule) to solve this.

Here is what my app.gwt.xml looks like now :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <module rename-to='minoscrossfit'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
  <extend-property name="locale" values="fr"/>
  <extend-property name="locale" values="fr_CA"/>
  <extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>                                     
  <inherits name='com.bradrydzewski.gwt.calendar.Calendar' />
  <inherits name='com.bradrydzewski.gwt.calendar.theme.google.Google' />
  <inherits name='com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.gwt-dnd'/>
  <entry-point class='com.afrsoftware.minoscrossfit.client.MinosCrossfit'/>
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>
 </module>
```

A little project->clean in eclipse seems to have helped solving my issue.

I add a similar problem after changing the app.gwt.xml and it was because someone in my team (probably me) had committed a file that is not supposed to be committed (the nocache.js) so the new jars used in the project were not in this file. Changing the app.gwt.xml provoked a recompilation of the app and a new nocache.js file (with all the needed functions from the jars) was generated.

Comment: I got the same problem, however I'm not able to fix it using the direction on the reference link. In my code I'm using `param.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)` where param is a string. I though it should've worked according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063102/using-locales-with-javas-tolowercase-and-touppercase). Any thoughts?