# How to uppercase a Java String except the accented characters

Tags: java, string, special-characters

I have a webapp that calls a webservice passing a string parameter (a name) which is in an uppercase format and can contain accentuated uppercased characters. 
On the other side, the server webapp doesn't manage this kind of characters.

Then, the client webapp has to lowercase accentuated characters ONLY (ex : CLÉMENT > CLéMENT).

Do you know a quick (using utils ?) method/combination of methods to do that, without having to convert the String into a table of Char ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it looks like you'll have to convert the string to a `char[]` and work from there. Try something like this:

```
public static String convert(String in) {

    // put in the string the accented characters to be converted
    final String accented = "ÁÉÍÓÚ";
    char[] outChars = in.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0, n = outChars.length; i < n; i++)
        if (accented.indexOf(outChars[i]) != -1)
            outChars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(outChars[i]);

    return new String(outChars);

}
```

Use it like this:

```
String in = "CLÉMENT";    // input  string: CLÉMENT
String out = convert(in); // output string: CLéMENT
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use regular expressions for detecting accented characters. But if the number of accented characters is small, a simple `indexOf()` operation would suffice

Comment: Thank you Oscar I used your solution. Yes I also checked for regular expressions but the number of accented characters in a name is small obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an odd requirement, but here is a solution:

```
  /** matches non-ASCII upper-case letters */
  private static final Pattern UPPER =
                        Pattern.compile("[\\p{javaUpperCase}&&[^\\p{Upper}]]+");

  private static String lowerNonAscii(String str, Locale locale) {
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher matcher = UPPER.matcher(str);
    int start = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
      String nonMatch = str.substring(start, matcher.start());
      String match = str.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end())
          .toLowerCase(locale);
      buffer.append(nonMatch)
          .append(match);
      start = matcher.end();
    }
    String tail = str.substring(start, str.length());
    return buffer.append(tail)
        .toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "CL\u00C9MENT";
    System.out.println(test + " > " + lowerNonAscii(test, Locale.ENGLISH));
  }
```

Note that:

- Case is meaningless without locale, so you'll have to provide one
- There is no special handling for decomposed [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) - that is, when the letter and the accent are separate `char`s

Comment: Thank you, this is obsviously the most generic solution. And thanks again for all the details !

Answer (score 0):

Please read the accepted answer here: [Using Locales with Java's toLowerCase() and toUpperCase()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063102/using-java-string-tolowercaselocal-english).

If you use toUpperCase with a locale, the accented characters should be respected.

Comment: This doesn't seems to fit my exact need (lowercase only accented characters) Thank you anyway for the advice.