# Converting lowercase to uppercase in java

Tags: java, locale, uppercase

In my language there is both uppercase I and İ (yes I with . on it). I want the result to be English.

I used the `toUpperCase();` method, but it converts i to İ instead I.

It's ridiculous - there has to be some way to make the `toUpperCase();` method properly convert in English.

Comment: I think you need to change your locale.  Check this question and the answers:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063102/using-locales-with-javas-tolowercase-and-touppercase

Comment: Ohh thank you very much sir. I found the answer to my question there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the overload of [`toUpperCase` which accepts a `Locale` argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase(java.util.Locale)):

```
str.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Coincidentally, that method's Javadoc uses the Turkish İ as an example.