# string.ToLowerInvariant() in C# vs String.ToLowerCase(Culture.ROOT) in Java for Turkish İ

Tags: java, c#, turkish, tolower

I see a difference in behavior between C# (.NET v4.0) and Java for converting 'İ' to lowercase with "invariant" culture.

In Java, `"İ".toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)` returns `'i'`.

In C#, `"İ".ToLowerInvariant()` and `"İ".ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` both return `"İ"` but `"İ".ToLower(new CultureInfo("en-EN"))` returns `'i'`.

Looks like Java is doing the conversion correctly but C# is not. Is this a bug in C#?

Comment: C# is a large field. Which version of .NET / of the CLR do you use in your example? .NET 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.6?

Comment: Done. Added to the question.

Comment: `CultureInfo` value may affect character set used when performing conversion. English tend to use either ASCII or ISO-8859-1 by default, where `InvariantCulture` may using UTF-8 encoding that includes special Turkish `İ` character.

Comment: Just to clarify, `ToLowerInvariant()` is the equivalent of `ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` so you'd get the same output for those. [Good post](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/) related to the 'Turkish test'

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look. The letter of the question

> İ

is in fact

> U + 0130: Latin **Capital** Letter I With Dot Above

(*Character Map* quotation). It seems reasonable, IMHO, that in case of *Invariant Culture* (we have no right to use any culture either English or Turkish) `ToUpperInvariant()` method should return the letter itself 
(since it's *capital* already) and for `ToLowerInvariant` the result should be something like

> U + xxxx: Latin **Small** Letter I With Dot Above

However, we *don't have* such a letter:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

And since we don't have the letter required, all we can do is to leave the original one *intact*.

When we use, say `"en-EN"` (*English*) culture we have a right to correspond *Letter I With Dot Above* to just good old *English* `I` and thus return `i` for `ToLower()`.

Comment: I understand this. What I did not understand is how Java is able to convert it with `Locale.ROOT`. Do the above case conversion rules not apply to Java? Is this a bug in Java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063102/using-locales-with-javas-tolowercase-and-touppercase