# Android Studio textAllCaps turning letter "i" to caps in my native language as "İ". Do you know a way to avoid this?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio-3.0, non-english, turkish

I'm trying to learn Android Studio (v. 3.6.3).  I am setting the attribute `textAllCaps` to true in the XML code source for`TextView`, as follows:

```
"android:text="@string/quantity"
"android:textAllCaps="true"
```

However, on the screen, the word "*Quantity*" is capitalized incorrectly as "*QUANTİTY*" (the uppercase i is dotted).

The letter "İ" (dotted uppercase i, Unicode U+0130), is used in Turkish, not in English. The language for the app is English.

I could not figure this out. Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: Have you looked at the following question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063102/using-locales-with-javas-tolowercase-and-touppercase